# What is the longevity of dried belle saison yeast at room temperature?

Tags: beer, yeast

I am starting to brew beer and when I bought my kit the yeast was stored in a fridge and I forgot to put in my fridge when I got home.

It is dried "belle saison" yeast and was at room temperature for about 8 hours with a maximum temperature of 22°C.

If I refrigerate it over night will it be viable?

Answer (score 1):

It should not matter that much. if you order it online the postal service won't keep it refridgerated either.

Answer (score 1):

It is dried yeast, it will be fine.

You should how ever allow it to warm to room temperature before adding it to your wort. And, you should probably look at how to  rehydrate it before pitching or make a starter.

Answer (score 0):

Your dry yeast will be fine. The reason your kit was in the refrigerator was to preserve the hops. You don't need (or want) to chill your yeast before you use it.